# Java extract data from square brackets and put into square brackets in another string

Tags: java, regex

I have to strings

```
String src = "EOM[1].MON[0].SHIPPED";
String trgt = "lineItems[&3].lineItems[&1].shipped";
```

I need to get the value between `[]` from src and replace the value in `[]` in trgt. And they are positional.

The result looks like this

```
"lineItems[1].lineItems[0].shipped";
```

What is the easy way to do this?

Comment: What's the significance of `&3`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regex:

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\[\\d+\\]").matcher(src);
while (m.find()) {
    trgt = trgt.replaceFirst("\\[&\\d+\\]", m.group());
}
```

Comment: Technically, you don't need to escape `]`, but the symmetry of escaping both `[` and `]` is good too.

Comment: shmosel, thanks alot for the answer. It works great.